# Kendo UI editor refresh issue on Firefox after inserthtml

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-editor

I'm using the `"inserthtml"` command to insert HTML into a Kendo Editor:

```
var editor = $("#editor").data("kendoEditor");
editor.exec("inserthtml", { value: "<p></p><hr /><h3>Some Text</h3>" });

// and do refresh
editor.refresh();
```

When I do this in Firefox, the HTML tags will show as text instead of HTML content.

I also tested this on newer version of Kendo. [Here's a demo on Kendo UI Dojo.](http://dojo.telerik.com/AnEbe)

Is there a solution for this? Is it a bug in Kendo?

Comment: can see here : http://dojo.telerik.com/AnEbe/2

Answer (score 0):

Looks like a bug to me. You can open a bug report here:

https://github.com/telerik/kendo-ui-core/issues